# How to install and run apache-airflow on windows without problem

Tags: airflow

I tried to install Apache Airflow 2.2.4 on windows 10. When I finish and run airflow here are the errors it gives me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    from airflow.__main__ import main
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from airflow import settings
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 35, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG, conf  # NOQA F401
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1127, in <module>
    conf = initialize_config()
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 890, in initialize_config
    shutil.copy(_default_config_file_path('default_webserver_config.py'), WEBSERVER_CONFIG)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 245, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/webserver_config.py'
```

Comment: Try this out https://github.com/caxefaizan/airflow_kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

Following steps resolved similar issue for me, but not sure what resolved it

1) Makes sure your **wsl version is 2**. (Restart PC if you change wsl version)

2)Enable **Windows subsystem for Linux** and **Virtual Machine platform**. (Restart PC)

After this, I followed following tutorial:
https://towardsdatascience.com/run-apache-airflow-on-windows-10-without-docker-3c5754bb98b4

If u follow this, u will not be installing airflow ver 1.10.12 but apache airflow 2.2.4, and **instead of "airflow initdb" use "airflow db init"** command.

 Also, before running command "airflow db init" create an user, command for this (optional but I suggest run this command):

```
airflow users create --username admin --password admin --firstname <firstname> --lastname <lastname> --role Admin --email abc@gmail.com
```